# How to parse such type array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I got the next when I'm trying to do:

```
for item in serverResponse {
    print(item)
}
```

it gives me:

```
("0", {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Programming"
})
("1", {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Music"
})
```

How can I parse this array to take `name` there? I've confused with it =/

**UPDATE**

The full response is:

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "books": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Programming"
        }
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Music"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Provide the response you have, and what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to convert Json to an object to read `name`. Crude solution would be to parse for name. Better way of doing it is use [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) or [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper).

Answer (score 0):

If you get Json from your server you can use it:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest)!)!
}

func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSArray{
    let boardsDictionary = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSArray

    return boardsDictionary
}
```

Then use `myData = parseJSON(json)` and you can access name with

```
let data = myData[0] as! NSDictionary
let name = data["name"]! as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in serverResponse {
    let itemArray = (item as? NSDictionary)["books"] as? NSArray
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.count ; i++ ) {
        if let dic1 = itemArray[i] as? NSDictionary {
           let item: String!
           item = dic1["name"] as? String
           print(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like dealing with dictionaries in Swift. I find that objects behave better and are easier to manage - they're also safer.

So my suggestion is to parse your response into "Book" structs, then you can access the properties of these structs (id, name) easily.

It could be even better to make a class that does all the work.

For testing purposes I've reproduced your response like this:

```
let response: NSDictionary = ["name": "ABC", "books": [["id": 1, "name": "Programming"], ["id": 2, "name": "Music"]]]
```

Now let's first make our Book struct.

It will have the two properties, and also an initializer which will decode the content of each dictionary that's located in the array in the "books" key of your response. The initializer is failable because the content *might* not be decodable.

```
struct Book {
    let id: Int
    let name: String

    init?(_ object: AnyObject) {
        if let dictionary = object as? NSDictionary,
            dictId = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
            dictName = dictionary["name"] as? String {
            self.id = dictId
            self.name = dictName
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can make a class that will hold all the books. We need another initializer for that, which will iterate over the contents and create the objects with the structs:

```
class BooksManager {

    var books = [Book]()

    init(response: NSDictionary) {
        if let array = response["books"] as? NSArray {
            self.books = array.flatMap { Book($0) }
        }
    }

}
```

Ok, now we have finished writing the boilerplate code, we can use our toys.

Create an instance of the class:

```
let manager = BooksManager(response: response)
```

That's it! Now the class holds the objects and you can easily access their properties.

For example with a loop:

```
for book in manager.books {
    print("Book id: \(book.id), book name: \(book.name)")
}
```

Result:

> Book id: 1, book name: Programming
>   Book id: 2, book name: Music

And let's say you want the name of the first book:

```
if let nameOfFirstBook = manager.books.first?.name {
    print(nameOfFirstBook)
}
```

Result:

> Programming

Last example, let's say you want to collect all books names in an array:

```
let booksNames = manager.books.map { $0.name }
```

Result:

> ["Programming", "Music"]